# Can I call a Dialogflow intent from Angular?

Tags: html, node.js, angular, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am using NodeJS to handle webhook fulfillment for Dialogflow agent, but I need to call an intent from the HTML button (it can be on Angular) and avoid the user writes anything and the agent gives an automatic response.
Another way I can make it is by sending a text to the Dialogflow Messenger from my Angular app.